# Error "the type kafkaconsumer is not generic it cannot be parameterized with arguments"

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I'm facing a problem when I want to instantiate a KafkaProducer :

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
props.put("acks", "all");
props.put("retries", 0);
props.put("batch.size", 16384);
props.put("linger.ms", 1);
props.put("buffer.memory", 33554432);
props.put("key.serializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
props.put("value.serializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);
```

> **the type kafkaconsumer is not generic it cannot be parameterized with arguments**

I don't understand the error knowing that I'm following the official kafka javadoc in which they do exactly the same thing with the same dependency as mine:

https://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html

Can someone explain me this joke ?

Comment: What are your import statements?

Comment: May be you have another code fragment with **kafkaconsumer**, don't you? Can you show the whole class ?

Comment: Here is the entire class : https://gist.github.com/christopheblp/4211fb3bbc25c21bfa67d5a60886f2cf

Comment: the type **kafkaconsumer** is not generic... You're showing the wrong code

Comment: If that is your class file; then you are using the same class name of the class you are trying to use from another library. ```KafkaProducer.class``` is a Apache class. You will run into issues with packaging and which class is selected when using same name classes. EDIT: Which it is not impossible to use the same class name as another library; but requires special care when import statements are considered, ect. Probably is not really recommended either due to the issues that can arise.

Answer (score 6):

I am also getting same issue. But i realize after some moment i gave the class name 'KafkaProducer' . After changing my class name, same code is compiled successfully.
Hope this helps you. Can you post your full class code with class name and imports?

When i am looking further original KafkaProducer class definition, it is a generic class. for more info, you can check: https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was my problem. It's fixed now !

Answer (score 1):

Do not use KafkaProducer or Producer as class name as its considering that your class not from Kafka Jar

Answer (score 0):

Include below dependency

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
<artifactId>kafka_2.13</artifactId>
<version>2.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```